# LVM went into read-only file system mode. How to find out the reason?

Tags: linux, lvm

I got the same error as [Read-only root file system - ext3 error?](https://serverfault.com/questions/37600/read-only-root-file-system-ext3-error).

There is no error log in /var/log/message. Because root (/) is read-only, no log can be recorded.

How can I find out the root cause?

Comment: How is this different from that question?

Answer (score 3):

Chances are very good the reason got logged on the ring-buffer. `dmesg` will probably have the error that would have been logged.